# windows Pycharm project interpreter nothing to show

Tags: pip, pycharm, setuptools

I was using Pycharm in windows and when I tried to check my project interpreter and clicked **install packaging tools**, something happened wrong.

[image]

The error turned out:

> *error:[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\users\Username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg'*

I followed some tutorial online to upgrade my pip and setuptools, pip is now 10.0 and setuptools 47.1.1, but every time I open the settings, all the way same and the **'setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg'** keeps showing up even I delete it each time.

I was running under python 3.7, Pycharm 2018.03, Anaconda 5.4. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 44):

Support by JetBrains advised me such a fix:

> Could you please try the following steps:

> 1. Close your project in PyCharm
> 2. Create a backup of your .idea/ folder
> 3. Remove .idea/ folder
> 4. Re-open your project

It's work for me, maybe help

Comment: It's the only thing that worked for me. I tried re-installing both pycharm and python but it was the project that was the problem after all.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Answer (score 14):

Had the same issue but for MacOS. It worked when I removed the `.idea/` directory and reopened the project.

Comment: Close the PyCharm first, and then remove `.idea/`. it works for me.

Comment: where is this .idea/ located please could someone elaborate?

Comment: It's a hidden folder. On MacOS, `Cmd+shift+.` displays all hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with PyCharm Community Edition (CE) for mac. No idea why the Python Interpreter tab shows this weird behavior but the interpreter should still be viewable through this path in Preferences:                                         Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Nothing to show here " in add packages or "error in loading python packages" Try uninstall the Python interpreter and reinstall it. Most of the Python version above 3.7 showing this error. Use python3.7 or earlier. Python 3.7 is good